# Symfony: how to set a template from another module?

Tags: symfony1

any time i write this:

```
$this->setTemplate('module/action');
```

I'm getting this error:

> The template
>   "module/actionSuccess.php" does not
>   exist or is unreadable in "".

So.. how to set a template from another module ?

Javi

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [API Documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfAction#method_settemplate):

```
$this->setTemplate('action', 'module');
```